# How to identify line mentioned as "global code" in JavaScript stacktrace

Tags: javascript, web

Sentry is notifying me of errors, with a stacktrace that starts with `at global code (https://www.<mydomain>.com:1:49)`

In my `header` tag I have several scripts.

How can I know which script tag, and which line of it, is causing the error?

Comment: You may need to upload your sourcemaps to Sentry.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Since it says "global code", doesn't it mean that it's supposed to come from an inline script, as opposed to a script loaded with a "src" attribute?

Comment: `Global code` usually means the statement is not part of a function.

Comment: Thanks, that's very interesting to know. That is more or less the essence of my question. Does the fact that between parentheses it is my home page's URL, and not a script URL, mean that it comes from inline code, and not a loaded script, or not?

Comment: No, there is no such distinction - it just means that the code is run in the topmost "scope" rather than inside a function (other scope). The only way to distinguish the source file I can think of, is by throwing an exception and inspecting the stacktrace.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I am confused as to your suggestion to throw an exception. From the stacktrace I get through Sentry, it is already an exception. You mean reproduce it locally? I can't do that, I have no idea what caused the problem.

Comment: Have you uploaded sourcemaps in Sentry? If yes - then the error might be coming from a browser extension rather than your code. If not - sourcemaps will allow you to see the original line in the source code where the error occurred.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. What if the error was caused by third party code, for example the Drift widget? I guess uploading my source files wouldn't change much, would it?

Comment: Obviously, your sourcemaps cover only your own code - third-party code will be minified. And if the widget runs in IFRAME - I have some doubts whether Sentry will catch its errors.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's funny you'd mention iframes, because the error I am getting is `Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.<my-domain>.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.` and I don't use iframes on my website, except for the (exceptionally terrible) Drift widget

Comment: But I don't know whether the code triggering this error is mine, trying to access Drift's iframe, or vice versa, or whether it's someone trying to do cross site something

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25098153/5962802 - probably you're trying to access something inside the IFRAME.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That's the thing, I don't think I am. I am using Drift's SDK, but apart from that I don't think I am meddling with its iframe.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That's the thing, I don't think I am. I am using Drift's SDK, but apart from that I don't think I am meddling with its iframe.